# C# Linq Projecting Anonymous type onto an interface

Tags: c#, linq, projection

Is it possible to project using a Select onto a anonymous type?

Here is some example code

```
public interface ITest
{
    string A{get;}
    int B{get;}
}

string[] names = { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Mary", "Jay" };
IQueryable<ITest> query =
    from     n in names.AsQueryable()
    select   new {A = n.ToUpper(), B = 2012};
```

The above code causes a

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Note: I can make the above code work if I were to define a class Test that implements ITest and then project into that class using:

```
select   new Test {A = n.ToUpper(), B = 2012};
```

**Why?** I am trying to see if I can only define the interface and not have to define the concrete implementation of the object and have Linq create me the object.

Comment: Why you want an `IQueryable` result and not an `IEnumerable` one?

Comment: *I am trying to see if I can only define the interface and not have to define the concrete implementation* ...without some dynamic code generation, it won't happen like this. You **must** have a concrete object. You will either have a compile time concrete type, or a runtime generated type.

Comment: IQueryable because in reality I am going after a database. The code above was just as an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can select into an anonymous type, but you can't both select into an anonymous type and then use those objects as if they implemented an interface.  The reason is that the anonymous type doesn't implement the interface even though they have the same properties, in both type and name.  There isn't a way to define that an anonymous type implements an interface. If you want to use objects via their interface implementations, you have to select into a concrete type that implements that interface.

> Anonymous types are class types that derive directly from object, and that cannot be cast to any type except object. The compiler provides a name for each anonymous type, although your application cannot access it. From the perspective of the common language runtime, an anonymous type is no different from any other reference type.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

I can certainly sympathize with your intent here.  It would be nice if the compiler could intuit that the type meets the interface definition when the type is anonymous, but that's really only applicable when the interface consists strictly of read-only properties.  The minute your interface defines properties with setters or methods, it's not possible for an anonymous type to implement it.  On the other hand, if you're using the anonymous type as it's intended -- as a short-term temporary type for a particular use -- you can simply reference it's properties and you don't need the interface at all.

```
 var query = from     n in names.AsQueryable()
             select   new {A = n.ToUpper(), B = 2012};
 foreach (var item in query)
 {
      Console.WriteLine( item.A );
 }
```

Comment: "you can simply reference it's properties and you don't need the interface at all." - I cant do that, as the method needs to return the queried objects. (This is part of the DAL and I am going against a database, not a static array). I was just trying to determine if I could be lazy and get away without having to create the class! Your answer makes sense - I cant!

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this directly with anonymous objects, but you can achieve something very similar with the [Clay](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek6DynamicMalleableEnjoyableExpandoObjectsWithClay.aspx) framework:

```
public interface IPerson {
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}

public static void CastToCLRInterface() {
    dynamic New = new ClayFactory();

    var person = New.Person();
    person.FirstName = "Louis";
    person.LastName = "Dejardin";

    // Concrete interface implementation gets magically created!
    IPerson lou = person;

    // You get intellisense and compile time check here
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", lou.FirstName, lou.LastName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because anonymous types do not implement interfaces.

You have to create a class for this.

One option may be the [Duck Typing Project](http://www.deftflux.net/blog/page/Duck-Typing-Project.aspx) which essentially generates a wrapper class at runtime (and thus comes with a penalty to performance and memory consumption)

(Just for reference, Anonymous Types are real, concrete classes, generated by the C# compiler. The .net Runtime itself does not support them. The C# Compiler does not allow you to modify how it generates these classes. I have not tried to see if [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/roslyn) could help here.)

Comment: You could also create that class at runtime. And from what I heard the current Roslyn incarnation is completely passive.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Very true, just added a link to the Duck Typing Project which does exactly that. I really don't recommend using runtime class generations for types that the developer controls though, but it is an option indeed.